# What does it mean to get a "free upgrade" to the IS MKII lens with purchase of a Canon 550D?

Tags: canon-550d, kit-lens

I am going to buy a DSLR camera, the Canon 550D with the 18-55mm IS lens kit, and additionally, it has a free upgrade to IS MKII Lens.

I am a bit new to photography and after doing a certain amount of research, I could only understand that MKII is Mark II Lens, which are a bit heavier, better in quality and focus. Am I right in this or is there anything else to it?

Comment: Canon likes to use the term MKII for version 2 of a lens.

Comment: It is not better in quality. Mk I and Mk II are identical in terms of performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means, normally a 550D comes with the older 18-55 IS lens, and now you will get the 18-55 IS Mk.II instead.

Note that optically, the two are identical. The only improvement is IS algorithm (the algorithm, not hardware)

Other than that it is cosmetic : the silver band is now painted black instead.

In terms of performance, there is no difference between the two, and the new IS algorithm provides a very slight improvement during a very specific type of shooting (panning shot)

In short, they are the same. The one with a silver band is called Mk I, the one without is called Mk II.

If you want any in-depth information, you can look through the very long and detailed reveiw here:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-18-55mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-II-Lens-Review.aspx

The sales is just trying to make you think you are getting a big offer - upgrading the lens for free. Well, now you know there is no difference between the two, it really isn't that big a deal at all. At most, the sales is just trying to fool you.

Answer (score 6):

The free upgrade simply refers to the fact that you have the ability to get the newer version of that lens, which has been improved in a variety of ways, when you purchase that camera body with the older version of the lens. I presume that is simply because there are still some boxes of the 550D kit that have been sitting on retailer shelves for a while that are becoming difficult to sell since they have the older version of the lens. Its really more of a way to help retailers sell their old stock than anything else.